# divisibility of uniform distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, infinite-divisibility

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and identically distributed random variables.
Can $X+Y$ be a uniform distribution?
(Please prove.)

In other words, is a uniform distribution divisible?

The meaning of "divisible" is described at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_distribution).

> If, further, it can be expressed as the distribution of the sum of two or more independent identically distributed random variables, then it is divisible: Z = X1 + X2.

I read [this article](http://godplaysdice.blogspot.jp/2008/04/uniform-distribution-as-sum.html) and it said that it is impossible.
But I could not understand its proof.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786379/can-sum-of-two-random-variables-be-uniformly-distributed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a direct argument.

Suppose independent $X_1,X_2 \sim X$, and $X_1+X_2$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.

$X$ is supported on $[0,1/2]$.

For any $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1/4$,
$\alpha = P\left(X_1+X_2 \in [0,\alpha]\right) \le P(X \in [0,\alpha])^2$ so $P(X \in [0,\alpha]) \ge \sqrt{\alpha}$. Similarly, $P(X \in [1/2-\alpha,1/2]) \ge \sqrt{\alpha}$.

Consider the event that $X_1+X_2 \in [1/2-\alpha,1/2+\alpha]$, that the sum is within $\alpha$ of $1/2$. The probability is $2\alpha.$ Within this event are the disjoint events that $X_1 \in [0,\alpha] \wedge X_2 \in [1/2-\alpha,1/2]$ and that $X_2 \in [0,\alpha] \wedge X_1 \in [1/2-\alpha,1/2]$. (Disjointness is implied by $\alpha \lt 1/4$.) These each have probability at least $\alpha$ and they are disjoint, so in fact they have probability exactly $\alpha$, and $P(X \in [0,\alpha])=P(X \in [1/2-\alpha,1/2]) = \sqrt{\alpha}$.

This completely determines the distribution of $X$:

$$\textrm{CDF}_X(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{x} & x \in [0,1/4] \newline 1-\sqrt{1/2-x} & x\in[1/4,1/2]\end{cases}.$$

However, this doesn't work. The convolution square is not uniform. You can see this without integrating because the event that $X_1+X_2 \in [0.49,0.51]$ must get its whole probability from $X_1 \in [0,0.01] \wedge X_2 \in [0.49,0.5]$ and $X_2 \in [0,0.01] \wedge X_1 \in [0.49,0.5]$. However, $X$ has positive density around $0.25$, which means that the probability that $X_1+X_2 \in [0.49,0.51]$ is greater than $0.02$. Thus, the convolution square of $X$ is not uniform.

Answer (score 4):

How about this...

Uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$ has [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory))

$$
\varphi(t) = \frac{\sin t}{t}
$$

Suppose $X,Y$ are IID and $Z:=X+Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$.
Of course $X,Y$ are bounded:
$$
\mathbb P[X>1]^2 = \mathbb P[X>1, Y>1] \le \mathbb P[Z>2] = 0
$$
so $\mathbb P[X>2]=0$.  Similarly $\mathbb P[X<-2]=0$.  The characteristic function of a bounded random variable is an entire function.  But the characteristic function $\psi(t)$ of $X$ and $Y$ satisfies
$$
\psi(t)^2 = \varphi(t)
$$
so it cannot be differentiable at $t=\pi$, where $\varphi(t)$ changes sign.

> More... $\varphi(\pi)=0$ so $\psi(\pi)=0$. But if $\psi'(\pi)$ exists, we get $-1/\pi = \varphi'(\pi) = 2\psi(\pi)\psi'(\pi) = 0$, contradiction.

Comment: can't one relax this assumption that X and Y have identical distribution? (excluding a delta-function distribution, I would think that the independence of X and Y is sufficient)

Comment: For non-identical distribution, see the link in Carlo's comment.